# Getting error args.includes is not a function node js

Tags: node.js, npm

I have node -v
v4.4.4

and npm -v
5.1.0

and I got the error :-
**args.includes is not a function node js. This is probably not a problem with npm.**

Please help for the same.

The sample code is as follow:-

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const REST_API_PROD = '.';
const REST_API_DEV = '/ms-si-api';
var args = process.argv.slice(2);

const readFile = path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/api-host.template');
fs.readFile(readFile, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
}
const isProd = args.includes('--prod');
console.log(isProd)
var result = data.replace(/{%host%}/g, isProd ? REST_API_PROD : REST_API_DEV);
const writeFile = path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/api-host.ts');
fs.writeFile(writeFile, result, 'utf8', (err) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
});
```

});

Comment: We cannot help you if you won't provide code where this error happens

Comment: Please see the code: on code  
    const isProd = args.includes('--prod');
I am getting this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says it all. Your Node.js version simply does not have support for `Array.prototype.includes`. You need to upgrade Node.js to at least version 6.0 to get it.

See http://node.green/#ES2016-features-Array-prototype-includes